# ROS2 Node (Robomaster driver) getting disconnected after launching realsense node

Tags: ros2, communication, ros-foxy, realsense-camera

I am trying to setup nav2 stack for robomaster ep-core Robot. I have two systems,

1. Jetson Nano (running Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy) on robot to collect scan data from realsense camera and cmd vel from joystick/nav.
2. PC (running Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy) to launch robot and navigation launch files.

Both systems are in the same network and are communicating over WiFi.

As soon I launch the camera node in Jetson nano, the robot gets disconnected. The robot server randomly connect and immediately gets disconnected.
(I can control robot launched in desktop with joy node connected to jetson nano).

[image]
Robomaster driver Node (main.launch)

[image]
Intel realsense Node (rs_launch.py)

I have tried connecting everything to one system(desktop) and it works fine. I can even map ,as long as cable supports.

Please help me solving this issue. I have no idea why the camera node is interrupting robot communication.

Answer (score 0):

The Robomaster signals were somehow interrupted by the jetson nano signals when the camera node was started (even the realsense-viewer).The reason was two wifi antennas(nano and robomaster controller) were placed very close to each other but after moving the antennas away things started working fine.

Comment: How far away did they need to be moved and what sort of antennas (type/length) were they?